# enable an asp.net panel on dropdownlist onselectindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to enable a panel based on dropdownlist selected value.

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (ddl.SelectedValue == "A")
        {
          lnk.Style.Add("Display", "block");
          panel1.Visible=true;
          panel1.Enabled=true;
        }
     }
```

The panel is not getting displayed. I have set autopastback property of dropdownlist to true.Can someone please help me.

Comment: have you put panel1.Visible==true

Comment: try to remove double quotation mark on "true".

Like:
panel1.enabled = true;
Hope it helps.

Comment: @lrb Please formt your code with tags and double check your syntax. You only encourage confusion when you provide incorrect info. It should be `panel1 = true;` The `Enabled` property on the `Pane`l is of `bool` type. Not `string`.

Comment: yes i have included that as well.But still not getting displayed.

Comment: removed the quotes but it doesnt help.

Comment: have you tried using break point? Does it execute your if statement?

Comment: `.Enabled` needs to be in the correct case. C# is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: @user3462803:yes, the statements are executed but the panel does not get displayed.

Comment: Have you tried @meda 's answer? panel1.Visible = true; maybe on your onload you have set panel1.Visible = false? try to comment that or put it inside an if statement. ex:   if (!IsPostBack == true) {panel1.Visible = false;}

Answer (score 2):

should be without the quotes:

```
panel1.Enabled = true;
```

but if you wanted to show hide a panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Visible="False" >                
...
</asp:Panel>
```

then the right way would be

```
panel1.Visible = true;//false to hide
```

Comment: `.Visible` is misspelled :)

Comment: @JWLim should it be lower case?

Comment: Upper! For both `Enabled` and `Visible`.